# RedHawk-SDR SCA compliant certification

Tags: redhawksdr

I am using RedHawk v2.1.0 . Does anyone know how to prove that RedHawk-SDR confirms to the SCA(Ver.2.2) specification? Is there the evidence conforming to the SCA specification, or is there a verification/certification tool in RedHawk-IDE? Alternatively, if You have proved that RedHawk-SDR is compliant with the SCA specification, please tell me how to do the method.

THank Youssef-san for document 
https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/redhawk/releases/download/2.0.0/SCASpecification-REDHAWK-2.0.0.pdf

I understood that RedHawk deviates from the SCA specification. However, I must make the evidence of SCA-compliance. Please tell me the method of how to make the evidence of SCA-compliance. Of course we believe that it is inevitable for some to deviate.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that REDHAWK is currently SCA-based, not SCA-compliant, It might be, but whether or not... I think it is not a guarantee for the future. I believe it was in previous versions. REDHAWK extends SCA (as described in the [document](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/redhawk/releases/download/2.0.7/SCASpecification-REDHAWK-2.0.0.pdf)) with great features indeed... like the python sandbox. I don't know why the developers decided trail a path away from SCA. This question is up to them to answer. That's why there's no reason for a SCA Validation Tool in REDHAWK.

[previously](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/Documentation/blob/13ebf34b48708d623d42faf18757b867e3ffad0b/mainch3.html#L1217) on a spd.xml file you had:

```
<softpkg id="id" name="name" type="sca_compliant" version="version">
```

[now](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/Documentation/blob/13ebf34b48708d623d42faf18757b867e3ffad0b/mainch3.html#L1219) the code generators give you:

```
<softpkg id="id" name="name" type="2.0.7" version="version">
```

`type` is now the REDHAWK version.

Answer (score 0):

Redhawk deviates from the sca specification and has documents of the differences here: https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/redhawk/releases/download/2.0.0/SCASpecification-REDHAWK-2.0.0.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. I added it to the question. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Although, the SCA specification is widely available, the information on how to establish, and sustain testing an SCA based SDR is not [[1]](https://www.wirelessinnovation.org/sdr10). There are some companies that certificate if your solution is SCA complience. I had a opportunity to see a presentation of SAIC which showed how they did it, but it was almost 8 years ago. If you want to check, I found this presention called `2010-4A-Navarro-presentation.pdf` available [here](https://www.wirelessinnovation.org/assets/Proceedings/2010/2010-4a.zip).

Besides, if you check the [SCA v2.2.2. specification](https://sds.wirelessinnovation.org/assets/sca_version_2_2_2.pdf) in section `4 ARCHITECTURE COMPLIANCE`, you will see a step-by-step about how it works.