# Redhawk 1.10 and GNU Radio component integration

Tags: redhawksdr

I am trying to add components of GNU Radio in Redhawk 1.10. I have redhawk and GNu installed. I have been able to add components from GNUhawk but I want a few components from GNU Radio too. 
How can I do it?? Can anyone explain this?

How can I do it?? Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll get support for that version of REDHAWK. Also, gnuhawk is deprecated. If you want a gnuradio integration, take a look at a more recent [work](https://github.com/GeonTech/gnuradio-redhawk) from [GeonTech's Blog](http://geontech.com/gnuradio-redhawk-integration/). According to their post, you are able to place a whole gnuradio Flowgraph inside a REDHAWK component.

Comment: the components added from GNU Radio in Redhawk are SCA compliant are not??

Comment: have you ever tested any simple FM/ AM waveforms in any version of Redhawk and they were transmitted and received successfully?? if yes can you share those property settings?

Comment: REDHAWK is based on SCA 2.2.2, born from OSSIE, please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46231021/redhawk-sdr-sca-compliant-certification) to understand better. I would say that they are not SCA-compliant. And yes.. I have tested a FM modulator/demodulator. It was a custom implementation using [liquid-dsp](https://github.com/jgaeddert/liquid-dsp). My hardware was ADI's FMCOMMS3. I have also tested [another way](https://github.com/rodrigo455/gnuradio-nbfm) to use gnuradio for REDHAWK 2.1

Comment: Did you find any latency during FM transmission and receiving??

Comment: I have tried adding these components but they require OSSIE 2 and I have OSSIE 1. Is there a way out to upgrade to OSSIE 2 using same existing platform of Redhawk?

Comment: yep. using gnuradio gave me latency... I guess that's why I went to a custom implementation. I think OSSIE is the REDHAWK core-framework, You would need to reinstall it. I recommend a complete fresh installation though